# Python regex matching return all matches

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have strings consisting of letters and numbers, like:

Ex1: "Phone 18020210 914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag"

Ex2: "Phone 18020210 N 0914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag"

Ex3: "Phone 18020210 N0914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag"

I would like to find the numbers that occurs like "914 171 717" and "0210 914 171", eg. the nine digit number can either be preceded by a zero, or a space.

I tried this:

`re.findall('[\s|0]\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s',Ex1)`

But this expression only returns ['0210 914 171 '], while I would like it to return both numbers : ['0210 914 171 ','914 171 717']

It is probably a quick fix, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `[\s|0]?\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s?` also you can use `[\s\d]+` that is shorter and better to read.

Comment: Square brackets denote a character class, not a group.

Comment: When trying ```re.findall('[\s|0]?\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s?',Ex1)``` I still only get: ['0210 914 171 ']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'\b0?\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\b', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/85szAb/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `0?` - an optional `0`
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\s\d{3}` -  whitespace, three digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ltVDxg):

```py
import re
s = 'Phone 18020210 914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag\nEx2: "Phone 18020210 N 0914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag\nPhone 18020210 N0914 171 717 mailbox 43, 1003 Florvaag'
print( re.findall(r'\b0?\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\b', s) )
# -> ['914 171 717', '0914 171 717']
```